# Trouble parsing json command out

Tags: json, ansible

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I've parsed json like this so many times I've lost count, not sure why this is giving me issue.

Here is the *valid* JSON my command is returning.

```json
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "message": "ok",
                    "status": "True",
                    "type": "Healthy"
                }
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "creationTimestamp": null,
                "name": "controller-manager",
                "selfLink": "/api/v1/componentstatuses/controller-manager"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "message": "ok",
                    "status": "True",
                    "type": "Healthy"
                }
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "creationTimestamp": null,
                "name": "scheduler",
                "selfLink": "/api/v1/componentstatuses/scheduler"
            }
        }
     ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```yaml
- name: "validating controlplane is operational"
  block:
    - name: "querying kube component status"
      command: kubectl --kubeconfig={{ remote_cert_dir }}/admin.kubeconfig get componentstatuses -o json
      register: controlplane_check

    - name: "registering fact: 'kube_status'"
      set_fact:
        kube_status: "{{ controlplane_check.stdout|from_json }}"

    - name: "verifying all controlplane components are healthy"
     assert:
        that:
          - item.conditions[0].status == "True"
        fail_msg: "ERROR: {{ item.metadata.name }} is unhealthy"
        success_msg: " {{ item.meteadata.name }} is healthy"
      with_items:
        - "{{ kube_status.items }}"
```

Here is the error I get:

```
TASK [../../roles/validate-controlplane : verifying all controlplane components are healthy] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 01 October 2020  12:48:55 -0700 (0:00:00.074)       0:00:02.055 ******
fatal: [st53p01nt-quju11200101.example.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'metadata'\n\nThe error appears to be in 'kubernetes/on-prem/automation/roles/validate-controlplane/tasks/main.yml': line 12, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: \"verifying all controlplane components are healthy\"\n      ^ here\n"}
```

When I remove the variables in the success/fail statements, it barks here:

```
TASK [../../roles/validate-controlplane : verifying all controlplane components are healthy] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 01 October 2020  12:47:23 -0700 (0:00:00.070)       0:00:02.105 ******
fatal: [st53p01nt-quju11200101.example.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'item.conditions[0].status == \"True\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.conditions[0].status == \"True\"): 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'conditions'"}
```

Normally I don't even use the `from_json` intermediary step but I added it here in my troubleshooting efforts. Maybe its lack of sleep but I don't see what in the world I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40284981/2123530. It seems the `items` key on a dictionary is clashing with Ansible internal builtin methods

Comment: Yep that was it. I just renamed the conflicting key  before I piped it thru from_json. Thx